# How do I use a volume created by the docker volume command?

Tags: docker

Using Docker 1.9.1, I can create a volume like so

```
docker volume create --name minecraft-data
```

Which works just fine

```
docker volume inspect minecraft-data
[
    {
        "Name": "minecraft-data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/minecraft-data/_data"
    }
]
```

Then I tried using that volume with `--volumes-from` but that didn't work

```
docker run --detach --interactive --tty \
  --volumes-from minecraft-data \
  -e VERSION=LATEST \
  -e EULA=TRUE \
  -p 25565:25565 \
  itzg/minecraft-server
Error response from daemon: Unable to find a node fulfilling all dependencies: --volumes-from=minecraft-data
```

How do I use a volume created by the `docker volume` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`docker volume create` man page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) mentions that you are supppose to use that data volume with a mounted path:

> You create a volume and then configure the container to use it, for example:

```
$ docker volume create --name hello
hello

$ docker run -d -v hello:/world busybox ls /world
```

> The mount is created inside the container’s /world directory.

So you don't need --volumes-from here: [you need to create a bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems)

```
- v minecraft-data:/apath
```

That will allow your container to access data from the volume container `minecraft-data` in `/apath`.